# Cannot edit a Drupal contact form

Tags: forms, drupal

I have this site running Drupal 8.1.3 with a contact form I need to edit. The site was done by someone else, the form was used and Drupal won't let me edit it.

I need to edit a form field of the type "list". Currently, it is allowing the visitor to select from the following values (in 
/admin/structure/contact/manage/date_form/fields/contact_message.date_form.field_location/storage):

**Las Vegas|Las Vegas**

**Los Angeles|Los Angeles**

**St. Gallen|St. Gallen**

**New York|New York**

**San Francisco|San Francisco**

If I am not mistaken, this represents:
value|label

[image: This is how the form field looks like]

I need to edit or remove the label on one of these entries (the label only):

**St. Gallen|St. Gallen - coming soon**

Does anyone know where this information is stored? How do I best fix it?

Comment: Please read the tags **before** posting your question.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If form is done using webforms module: you need admin rights to access
/admin/content/webforms 
select your form from the list and click 'edit' after that 'webform' tab and the webform fields will show up, ready to be edited. Find field you need and edit it.

If form is done by custom module, then you need to look inside that module code.